# Efficient way to get closest pay day to a given date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to find the closest payday from a given date.

Let's say we know payday are every 14 days and that January 6, 2022 was one of them. What is the most efficient way to find the next payday for a given date (the date is the beginning of a week actually) from a known payday?

Here is a current working ugly implementation

```
    def payday_first_date
      # TODO: Very reliable, but very inefficient
      @payday_first_date ||= begin
        date = known_pay_day
        date -= 14.days until date < given_date
        date += 14.days until date > given_date
        date
      end
    end

    def known_pay_day
      # Thursday January 6, 2022 was a payday
      @known_pay_day ||= Date.new(2022, 2, 17)
    end
```

The given_date could be in the future and also in the past. It can be a date from another year aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some other input cases and expected output? I'm not completely getting the problem.

Comment: Sorry @SebastianPalma if my explanation wasn't clear. Dates are not known. We define one date that we know was a payday and then from this date every 14 days (2 weeks) is a payday. You can go backward or forward it will always work. The question is what is the most efficient way to find the next closest future payday of a date from one known date. It has to work for future/past years aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define the known pay date and two helper methods.

```
require 'date'
```

```
def date_str_to_date_obj(date_str)
  DateTime.strptime(date_str, "%B %d, %Y").to_date
end
```

```
known_date = date_str_to_date_obj("January 6, 2022")
  #=> #<Date: 2022-01-06 ((2459586j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

---

For presentation only:

```
def date_obj_to_date_str(date_obj)
  date_obj.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %A")
end
```

```
date_obj_to_date_str(known_date)
  #=> "January 06, 2022, Thursday"
```

---

The main method follows.

```
def closest_pay_day(known_date, target_date)
  nbr_pay_dates    = (target_date - known_date)/14.0
  last_pay_date    = known_date + nbr_pay_dates.floor * 14
  next_pay_date    = last_pay_date + 14
  (next_pay_date - target_date < target_date - last_pay_date) ?
  next_pay_date : last_pay_date
end
```

---

Suppose the target date is after the known pay date.

```
target_date_str = "March 26, 2022"
```

Then

```
target_date = date_str_to_date_obj(target_date_str)
  #=> #<Date: 2022-03-26 ((2459665j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date_obj_to_date_str(target_date)
  #=> "March 26, 2022, Saturday"
```

The closest pay period to the target date is therefore

```
closest = closest_pay_day(known_date, target_date)
  #=> #<Date: 2022-03-31 ((2459670j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date_obj_to_date_str(closest)
  #=> "March 31, 2022, Thursday"
```

which is

```
(target_date- closest).to_i
  #=> -5
```

days before the target date, meaning 5 days after the target date.

---

Now suppose the target date is before the known pay date.

```
target_date_str = "October 19, 2021"
```

Then

```
target_date = date_str_to_date_obj(target_date_str)
  #=> #<Date: 2021-10-19 ((2459507j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date_obj_to_date_str(target_date)
  #=> "October 19, 2021, Tuesday"
```

```
date_obj_to_date_str(closest_pay_day(known_date, target_date))
  #=> "October 14, 2021, Thursday"
```

Comment: Alternatively `x = (target_date - known_date) %14; target - (x > 7 ? x - 14: x)`